# Is there a way to constrain a type parameter to SqlDbType?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0

I'm looking to constrain a type parameter to SqlDbType for a generic factory method. Here's my attempt at the signature:

```
    private static SqlParameter SqlParameterFactory<ValTYpe>(String 
       ParamName, SqlParamInOrOut Direction) where ValTYpe: SqlDbType
```

This gives the error: "Error    1   'System.Data.SqlDbType' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter."

I sense it is doable, but it's my sytax... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SqlDbType` is an enum. Pass it as a parameter

```
  private static SqlParameter SqlParameterFactory(SqlDbType ValType, String  
   ParamName, SqlParamInOrOut Direction)
```